# Can I run a program that consumes a WCF service on Windows 2000?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-2000

We're hosting a WCF web service on a server running the latest version of Windows Server.

We have many different clients running different versions of Windows. For example, 2000, XP, Vista and a couple of Windows 7.

***Can*** I run a program that consumes a WCF service in Windows 2000? What do I need for a WCF service to run well on the client side?

Comment: Can you run .NET Framework on Windows 2000?  If so, you should be able to consume a service.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I can only install .NET 2.0 - I'm asking if I can consume WCF services with that version of .NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to consume WCF on windows server 2000 OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165457/how-to-consume-wcf-on-windows-server-2000-os)

Comment: @mellamokb: Not at all a duplicate. That mentions running the service host on Windows Server 2000. I'm asking about running a client application that consumes a WCF service in Windows 2000.

Comment: @SergioTapia: I'm reading that question again, and they're talking about the same thing.  It is a duplicate question.  "I can recompile Client app to framework 2.0. to able to run it on Windows Server 2000. But how I am gonna consume WCF?"

Answer (score 0):

A WCF service can be consumed by any client that can communicate with SOAP. The performance of the WCF service has nothing to do with the client OS. If performance is an issue with the WCF service it is most likely a connectivity or bandwidth issue from the client to the server. How you choose to consume the service is up to you. The WCF service will continue to run on your server and perform any methods you invoke from the client on the server.

Comment: This might be true in some (default/usual) cases.  But not all WCF services are SOAP.  I think they can be configured to be JSON-only, for example, or use memory streams.

Comment: I believe what you are referring to would be considered a rest based service and not a traditional wcf service. A traditional WCF service utilizes SOAP where a REST based service utilizes http.

Comment: You're correct.  I'm just saying it is an assumption, and the statement shouldn't be made that WCF always supports SOAP.  There are a lot of services that can be called WCF services that won't support it.  I can conceive of ways that the OP wouldn't know the difference - maybe they are very new to WCF, and maybe they didn't write it, and are just deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to answer your question without knowning the requirements of the web service which is exposed on the 'latest version' of windows.

The most important part of this will be "which binding(s) is/are being exposed by the WCF service".

If this is 'basicHttp' or 'wsHttp' you will be able to communicate with this service using a .Net 2.0 client (wsdl.exe proxy). If this is not the case, it will become harder to implement.

Bottom line; a Web Service is not tied in to the development platform it has been written on. The real important part of a web service is it's contract (which is described by WSDL). If the contract exposed can be consumed by .Net 2.0 tools, you can communicate.

If they cannot, you either have to use 'extensions' (like WSE) or go the manual route which i both advise not to take!

ps; WCF != WebServices. WCF is a toolkit that can be used to build a web service or rest service. "Traditional webservices used the Basic Profile 1.1" which consist only of XML, XSD, WSDL and SOAP.

hope this helps,